# ASP.NET Core over writing my URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a problem where the action in my controller called GiftCards is over-writing the actual URL/View page name.

```
public IActionResult SomeStupidName()
{
      return ("Checkout");
}
```

my url turns into

```
www.mywebsite.com/GiftCards/SomeStupidName
```

while I want it to be

```
www.mywebsite.com/GiftCards/Checkout
```

Some further detail would be that this is execute with an form-submit where the form has an

```
asp-action="SomeStupidName"
```

Comment: Nothing is _over writing your url_! The method is named `SomeStupidName` so of course it creates `../GiftCards/SomeStupdName` by default. If you want to change it, create a specific route definition or use attribute routing - [5 Ways to Build Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://stormpath.com/blog/routing-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that `www.mywebsite.com/GiftCards/SomeStupidName` means `SomeStupidName` is an action of controller `GiftCards` so `www.mywebsite.com/GiftCards/Checkout` means `Checkout` is an action of controller `GiftCards` but in your code you are returning `View` from `GiftCards` `action` not redirecting to other `action`. Lets suppose I have action name `Checkout`.

```
public IActionResult Checkout()
{
    return View("Checkout");
}
```

It will return the view `Checkout` when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/GiftCards/Checkout` so now I can redirect to action from any other action like:

```
public IActionResult SomeStupidName()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Checkout");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"Attribute Routing"** in Asp.Net Core. Return the proper view in your controller.Try this code !!

```
[Route("GiftCards/Checkout")]
public IActionResult SomeStupidName()
{
  return View("Checkout");
}
```

Attribute routing is set of attributes to map actions directly to route templates. We can mention rewrite url inside the *"()"* in *"[Route("")]"* Attribute.

More details about *attribute routing* in Asp.net core : [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: You should probably add examples of those routing attributes.

Comment: Update for @RajneeshMenoth answer, since "Edit queue was full" message displayed while editing the answer. Add above the action method "[Route("GiftCards/Checkout")]"